# How to check for a instance in back stack of activities and remove one of the activities

Tags: android, back-stack

I have `3 activities`, stacked one above another

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

- Now When I am in `D`, How to find that B is available in backstack
- Now when B is present in back stack remove only B from the stack
  A,B,C,D
- Then launch B again ... making result to be ACDB

Is this possible in android, How ?

PS: Do I need to post code ?.. let me know ... because there are just activities and no other logic

Comment: you want open activity B above D, so you stack will be ACDB ? use launch mode

Comment: @Basi ... correct !

Comment: use  launchMode = “singleTask”

Comment: check [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-activity-launchmode-explained-cbc6cf996802) and [this](https://medium.com/@iammert/android-launchmode-visualized-8843fc833dbe)

Comment: Why do you need to remove the activity B then relaunch again?

Comment: @Tommy ..... `SingleTask` as `@Basi` suggested workes somewhat but dosent solve the issue .... because I need `ABCD`.... further it becomes on launch of `B` with single task it is `ABCD` to AB .............but actually i need `ABCD` to `ACDB`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using ActivityManager. Below is the same code,

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService( ctx.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList =  m.getRunningTasks(10);
Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)itr.next();
    int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
    CharSequence desc= runningTaskInfo.description;
    int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
    String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName();
}
```

This will get you all the activities. For more detail, refer docs

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager

Comment: This answers the first half part of my question ... thank you

Answer (score -1):

In Your Base Activity Make an ArrayList of Type Activities.

```
public static ArrayList<Activity> activityArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

while changing activities just add a line in next activity

```
BaseActivity.activityArrayList.add(this);
```

these activities are add in your arrayList, now you can easy add or remove any activity on your choice from array list e.g i have create multiple function in Base Activity removing all activities or removing all except main

```
public static void finishAllExceptMain() {
  try {
    //Constants.logMessage(Constants.TAG, "outer Start Size: " + activityArrayList.size());
    int count = activityArrayList.size();
    while (count > 1) {
      count--;
      activityArrayList.get(count).finish();
      activityArrayList.remove(count);
    }

  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
}

public static void finishLastActivity() {
  int lastActivity = activityArrayList.size() - 1;
  activityArrayList.get(lastActivity).finish();
  activityArrayList.remove(activityArrayList.get(lastActivity));
}
```